# Sticky top menu in prestashop

Tags: jquery, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using a prestashop premium theme which has a sticky menu on scroll. On top of this menu, I added another module for a menu which is not sticky. I'm trying to make this second menu that I added to be sticky but I'm not sure how.
I attached screenshots to show you what I mean.
The first image shows both menus and the second image show the menu that it's sticky right now. So, I want both to be sticky on scroll.

Full menu:

[image]

Current sticky menu
[image]

I used this module to add the top menu which is not sticky:

```
{if $MENU != ''}
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="block_top_menu" class="sf-contener clearfix col-lg-12">
        <div class="cat-title">{l s="Categories" mod="blocktopmenu"}</div>
        <ul class="sf-menu clearfix menu-content">
            {$MENU}
            {if $MENU_SEARCH}
                <li class="sf-search noBack" style="float:right">
                    <form id="searchbox" action="{$link->getPageLink('search')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="get">
                        <p>
                            <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="position" name="orderby"/>
                            <input type="hidden" value="desc" name="orderway"/>
                            <input type="text" name="search_query" value="{if isset($smarty.get.search_query)}{$smarty.get.search_query|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </li>
            {/if}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/ Menu -->
{/if}
```

How can I make this menu sticky? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried using `position:fixed;` on the menu that isn't sticky?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the other menus stays on top when I scroll on the page. So even if I try to make it fixed is still under the other menu.

Comment: Is this the expected result? https://jsfiddle.net/rezyc4bt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit 2 files:

`/themes/ps_glori/css/global.css`

Line 2469, in the `#header > .nav`, change: `position: relative` with `position: fixed` and add: `width: 100%`

`/themes/ps_glori/css/modules/csmanagement/css/codespot-global.css`

Line 72, in the `.cs-sticky-fixed`, change `top: 0` with `top: 30px`.